# Problem with smooth scrolling in Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll, material-design, android-chips

I have a **ChipGroup** inside a `HorizontalScrollView` which is set to smooth scroll to a position when a **Chip** is clicked. They are connected to a `ViewPager` so when I click a **Chip** it swipes to a fragment in the `ViewPager`, and when I swipe the `ViewPager` it checks the corresponding **Chip**.

The problem is when I swipe the `ViewPager` the **Chips** check and position themselves how they are supposed to but when I click a **Chip** it just snaps to its position.

> This is how it look like when swiping:

[image]

> And this is how it looks like when clicking:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment {

    private Chip chip_all;
    private Chip chip_watching;
    private Chip chip_completed;
    private Chip chip_onhold;
    private Chip chip_dropped;
    private Chip chip_plantowatch;

    private HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
    private ChipGroup chipGroup;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private int widthScreen;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        chipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_group);
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        chip_all = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_all);
        chip_watching = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_watching);
        chip_completed = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_completed);
        chip_onhold = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_onhold);
        chip_dropped = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_dropped);
        chip_plantowatch = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_plantowatch);

        chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedListener);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        widthScreen = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        for (int index = 0; index <= chipGroup.getChildCount() - 1; index++) {
            chipGroup.getChildAt(index).setOnClickListener(chipsClickListener);
        }

        SectionsPageAdapter sectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPageAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    }

    private static class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentActivity) {
            super(fragmentActivity);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    selectedFragment = new ListALL();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selectedFragment = new ListWATCHING();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selectedFragment = new ListCOMPLETED();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    selectedFragment = new ListONHOLD();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    selectedFragment = new ListDROPPED();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    selectedFragment = new ListPLANTOWATCH();
                    break;
            }
            return selectedFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }
    }

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    chip_all.performClick();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    chip_watching.performClick();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    chip_completed.performClick();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    chip_onhold.performClick();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    chip_dropped.performClick();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    chip_plantowatch.performClick();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    };

    private ChipGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedListener = new ChipGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(ChipGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (group.getCheckedChipId()) {
                case R.id.chip_all:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                    break;
                case R.id.chip_watching:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                    break;
                case R.id.chip_completed:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                    break;
                case R.id.chip_onhold:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
                    break;
                case R.id.chip_dropped:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);
                    break;
                case R.id.chip_plantowatch:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(5, true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private ChipGroup.OnClickListener chipsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            view.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);

            if (chip_all.isChecked()) {
                Rect rr = new Rect();
                view.getDrawingRect(rr);
                scrollView.smoothScrollBy(rr.right - (widthScreen - r.right), 0);
            }

            if (chip_watching.isChecked()) {
                Rect rr = new Rect();
                view.getDrawingRect(rr);
                scrollView.smoothScrollBy(rr.right - (widthScreen - r.right), 0);
            }

            if (chip_completed.isChecked()) {
                Rect rr = new Rect();
                view.getDrawingRect(rr);
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(chip_completed.getLeft() - (widthScreen / 2) + (chip_completed.getWidth() / 2), 0);
            }

            if (chip_onhold.isChecked()) {
                Rect rr = new Rect();
                view.getDrawingRect(rr);
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(chip_onhold.getLeft() - (widthScreen / 2) + (chip_onhold.getWidth() / 2), 0);
            }

            if (chip_dropped.isChecked()) {
                Rect rr = new Rect();
                view.getDrawingRect(rr);
                scrollView.smoothScrollBy(r.right, 0);
            }

            if (chip_plantowatch.isChecked()) {
                Rect rr = new Rect();
                view.getDrawingRect(rr);
                scrollView.smoothScrollBy(r.right, 0);
            }
        }
    };
```

I tried replacing `.performClick()` with `.setChecked()` and adding `.smoothScroolTo()` but it still snapped the `HorizontalScrollView` instead of smooth scrolling.

> I'm trying to basically get this while still being able to scroll the `ViewPager`:

[image]